# Paypal API Express Checkout in PHP Payment error code 13113

Tags: php, paypal

We have tried and tested our site with Paypal sandbox and it works fully deducting the amount.

We switched the API details to Paypal and the links. We have tried with several paypal accounts to see if it works (all of them have enough funds for the transaction).

We recieve this back through the API on our returnUrl page -
The API Call Failed

```
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d07%2d15T19%3a31%3a43Z [CORRELATIONID] => 927a89205e54a           
[ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 65%2e1 [BUILD] => 3300093 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 13113               
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Buyer%20Cannot%20Pay%2e [L_LONGMESSAGE0] =>                          
The%20Buyer%20cannot%20pay%20with%20PayPal%20for%20this%20Transaction%2e [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )
```

Php to make the final API call -

```
$APIUSERNAME="*****";
$APIPASSWORD="***";
$APISIGNATURE="*****";
$ENDPOINT = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
//$ENDPOINT     = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";   
$VERSION      = "64"; 

//Build the Credential String:   
$cred_str = "USER=" . $APIUSERNAME . "&PWD=" . $APIPASSWORD . "&SIGNATURE=" .           
$APISIGNATURE . "&VERSION=" . $VERSION;

//Build NVP String for GetExpressCheckoutDetails   
$nvp_str = "&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&TOKEN=" . urldecode($token); 

//Lets combine both strings then make the API call
$req_str = $cred_str . $nvp_str; $response = PPHttpPost($ENDPOINT, $req_str);
```

The above array comes from when i recieve my final acknowledgment from paypal.

```
//check Response
if($doresponse['ACK'] == "Success" || $doresponse['ACK'] == "SuccessWithWarning") { 
echo "completed"; //just put to test  
include "finishtransaction.php"; //cancels my cart sessions
} else{
    echo "The API Call Failed"; print_r($doresponse); 
}
```

There is not much on google about this error, not even in the API error codes. Has anyone come accross this before?

Answer (score 7):

The [PayPal API Error Codes](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes) are admittedly not very helpful.

Error code 13113, or "The Buyer cannot pay with PayPal for this Transaction" means that PayPal has taken a security measure by refusing to process the transaction.  This can happen for one of the following reasons (there are more, but here are a few):

- The buyer does not have enough money in their account
- The buyer does not have enough money in their account, and there is a problem charging their credit card (if they have that set in their settings)
- The buyer has asked for a refund on another item from the seller, and PayPal has therefore blocked the buyer's account from transferring money to the seller until the situation has been resolved.
- The buyer is suspected of fraudulent activity, so there is a freeze on their accounts.
- The buyer's account is restricted to sending money to the specific seller for some other reason
- The buyer's account is entirely frozen for some specific reason

Unfortunately, there isn't much anyone can tell you without thoroughly looking through your code.  I would check my code and make sure all appropriate flags and what-not are set.  If you wait a few hours and are still getting the error (especially on multiple/new accounts), then you will need to contact PayPal.

I know it sucks, but only PayPal will be able to tell you why exactly the transaction is failing.

Comment: make sure you use `urlencode` on all the parameters.  you even use `urldecode($token)`, when I think you meant `urlencode($token)`

Comment: Thanks, but it did not seem to do it. Tried encode. Surely if it was a contributing factor sandbox would not have worked.

Comment: makes sense.  From what others have experienced, it seems like something you may just have to contact PayPal about.

Comment: I'd like to add that this indeed doesn't appear to be a technical error, but rather a straightforward transaction decline by either PayPal or the card issuer.